# how do Google analytics and omniture make ajax calls on link clicks and still follow the link

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-analytics, adobe-analytics

I need to add to code to a bunch of pages that will monitor links when clicked and send off an ajax request.

The response To The Ajax call is not relevant or required, but I need to be able to send it off reliably and then allow the link, or button, To just do what ever it was going to do before.

I know this is done by both Omniture and Google analytics code but after pouring through both of the JavaScript Libraries for those I cannot seem to figure it out.

Does anybody have any insight into how either of these guys handle this problem?

Thanks.

#### EDIT:

**Context**:  The reason I need to do this is because I am adding a call to a custom API on many different pages when a link is clicked (the actual link is text matched from CMS input so i can't REALLY know what it is).  It's going to hit many codebases with many approaches to what their links and buttons do.  sometimes then will have their own JS events, sometimes `onclick` handlers, sometimes be native links to the same window, sometimes a new window... the point is that whatever that click does... i am entering a *world of pain* if i try to cancel and re-start it.  I don't, and can't, control these codebases and I have to be very unintrusive with my approach here.  My thought is that I need to get the call out on a single click listener without doing `e.preventDefault()` or `return false` as that could likely break the page's intended functionality.

I thought about doing a synchronous ajax call but it just seems so dirty.  that and it's deprecated.  i really want to avoid that.  I know Omniture adds a 500ms delay but i don't know *HOW* they do that.

Comment: Google Analytics doesn't do it by default. See https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920 - they require you to add a `onclick` parameter to the links. I can't speak for Omniture, but it'd be fairly trivial to use JavaScript to intercept clicks on `a` elements, make a call, then redirect to the URL afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

If I get your question right you're looking for something that sends the requests without blocking the page navigations for example.

If yes then you might be looking for this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon

if there is no support of the send beacon method: you should use an img to get the job done. Read the description part of the article.

more details and the example can be found here:

https://www.w3.org/TR/beacon/#sec-sendBeacon-method

```
<html>
<script>
  // emit non-blocking beacon to record client-side event
  function reportEvent(event) {
    var data = JSON.stringify({
      event: event,
      time: performance.now()
    });
    navigator.sendBeacon('/collector', data);
  }

  // emit non-blocking beacon with session analytics as the page
  // transitions to background state (Page Visibility API)
  document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
    if (document.visiblityState === 'hidden') {
      var sessionData = buildSessionReport();
      navigator.sendBeacon('/collector', sessionData);
    }
  });
</script>

<body>
 <a href='http://www.w3.org/' onclick='reportEvent(this)'>
 <button onclick="reportEvent('some event')">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can't see why it got downvoted yet - maybe if you could explain it - I might see the reason then too...

Comment: I downvoted because `sendBeacon` is highly unlikely to be what GA and Omniture use, given that it's not supported in IE or Safari.

Comment: as far as I know - the implementation of GA etc., of course, will be more fail safe since for example back in 2012 the window.onunload event wasn't even fully supported - could imagine there are even fallbacks for that. nevertheless - the beacon API should get the OP started - implementing the fallbacks should be up to him. safari has it in its TP version already and IE is about to die ;)

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like there may just be a simple no-op loop involved.  I still have not found the part of the codebase that has this either in google or adobe analytics but this seems to work:

```
wait = function(delay){
    now = new Date().getTime();
    then = now +  parseInt(delay);
    while(now < then){
        now = new Date().getTime();
    }
    return delay;
}
```

this can be placed in a click listener to prevent the event from bubbling for `delay` milliseconds.  In my tests in Chrome if the delay exceeds `999` and the link has `target="_blank"` chrome seems to treat it as a popup and blocks it.  that's ok though because if you're doing a new window the current window is not destroyed and the ajax call has time to finish.

I think i'm going to try this even though it stinks because that amazing new beacon thing doesn't get the coverage I need.